# Am I going to lose access to cloud storage when my gold membership expires?

Tags: xbox-network

I currently have an Xbox Live gold membership, and I am uploading all my saved games to the Xbox 360 cloud storage.

[According to this article](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-live/game-saves-in-the-cloud/cloud-save-games) you need a gold membership to use cloud storage.

What I fear is, the day my gold membership expires, will I suddenly be unable to access my saved games?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your Xbox Live Gold membership expires, you'll still have read access to your cloud save games (see [here](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-live/game-saves-in-the-cloud/help#3788147730d9455b847398f6ab5559ac)). In order to use them in a game you'll have to copy them to another storage device so the game can make a new save, of course.

Comment: I tried to link directly to the question on Xbox Support that answers this question, but it doesn't seem to work. Just scroll down to "Cloud storage is only available to Xbox Live Gold members".

Comment: Thanks, this comment is still applicable 2.5 years later. One thing to note is that you can NOT access your cloud saves in game, you have to manage your storage options in the system settings and move the cached cloud data to a local storage device before using it in game.